# How to stop exposing multiple endpoint at client side in WCF

Tags: wcf, wcf-endpoint

suppose my wcf has many end point with different binding.so when user / client add service ref from VS IDE at then multiple endpoint related data expose & added in client config file at client side.

Can we design service in such a way as a result only one endpoint related address will be revealed at client side?

Suppose I have one service with HTTP & TCP related endpoint and I want when external customer will add our service from their VS IDE then they will see our HTTP endpoint address not TCP. So guide me how could I do this? How to design service end config file for my requirement?

here i am attaching a small sample code for multiple endpoint related in config file.

```
<services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="MulContractService" name="MyWCFLibrary.MultipleContract">
                <clear />
                <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MulContractBasicBinding"
                    name="MulContractBasicEndPoint" contract="MyWCFLibrary.IMultipleContract"
                    listenUriMode="Explicit">
                    <identity>
                      <dns value="localhost" />
                        <certificateReference storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="test1" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MulContractWsHttpBinding"
                    name="MulContractWsHttp" contract="MyWCFLibrary.IByeWorld"
                    listenUriMode="Explicit">
                    <identity>
                      <dns value="localhost" />
                        <certificateReference storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="test1" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MulContractWsHttpBinding"
                    name="MulContractWsHttp" contract="MyWCFLibrary.IHelloWorld"
                    listenUriMode="Explicit">
                    <identity>
                      <dns value="localhost" />
                        <certificateReference storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/MyWCFLibrary/MultipleContract/"
                    binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MulContractTCPBinding"
                    name="MulContractTCPEndPoint" contract="MyWCFLibrary.IMultipleContract" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MyWCFLibrary/MultipleContract/" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
```

### EDIT

here i am giving my new full code and just guide me does it work?

```
namespace CustomService
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IEmp
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetEmp();

    }

    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class BusinessLayer : IEmp
    {
        public BusinessLayer()
        {

        }
        public string GetEmp()
        {
            return "Casino";
        }

    }
} 

Config code at service end

<services>
      <service name="CustomService.BusinessLayer">

        <endpoint address="CustomerFactory" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="HTTPBindingConfig" name="CustomerFactoryHTTP"
          contract="CustomService.IEmp" listenUriMode="Explicit" />
      </service>

      <service name="CustomService.BusinessLayer">
        <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="HTTPBindingConfig"
          name="CustomerMasterHTTP2" bindingName="CustomerMaster" contract="CustomService.IEmp" />
      </service>
</services>
```

just tell me the above config will work?

in the above config i define two service tag with same name because my service full name with namespace is CustomService.BusinessLayer

is it ok or do i need to give unique name for each service tag?

my intention is i will have same service but with multiple service tag and when customer will add my service ref at their end then they will not be able to see all the endpoint.

my intention is not expose all endpoint & address to every client.

so guide me what i have done does it work or not....if not then rectify my config entry and tell me how could i restrict my endpoint not to expose each binding & address before all client. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not what you are looking for but you could easily add another service to your project and give it the endpoints you want your client to see. Then the existing service could be just for TCP or for both types. Under the covers of course both services would run the same code.

Adding a service is just like adding any other file, right click, add New Item, WCF service. Then you can use the WCF configuration Editor to configure it if you dont want to do it by hand.

For what it is worth here is a config with two services. You can see that the first service has two endpoints, an Http and a TCP while the second service exposes just the http endpoint. Your two services would then each implement IService and would delegate to a common class or library.

```
<services>
  <service name="Mynamespace.Service1">
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="HTTPBindingConfig" name="MyserviceHTTP"
      contract="Mynamespace.IService" listenUriMode="Explicit">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint  binding="netTcpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="TCPSecured" name="MyserviceHTTP"
      contract="Mynamespace.IService" />
  </service>
     <service name="Mynamespace.Service2">
   <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="HTTPBindingConfig" name="MyserviceHTTP"
      contract="Mynamespace.IService" listenUriMode="Explicit">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: thanks for reply.i am new in wcf so just do not understand what u said.r u trying to say that i will write one service and one contract but in config file i will have two service tag which will point my one service and one contract with different endpoint. is it possible ?

Comment: how far i know that service name has to be unique in config file. so if i give two same name for my service in config file then i may get error. so i like to request you can please write a small wcf full sample code here with config file....so i can visualize how to write code to achieve my goal.

Comment: this is a question and answer site, "does it work" is not a specific enough question

Comment: i really do not understand your config entry. it would be better if you come with small service & contract code with config entry to better visualization. if possible please write a small service & contract code with config entry. thanks a lot.

Comment: from your config code it seems that i need to write two service and contact code with different name but same functionality? is it ?

Comment: I have updated the answer to make it a little clearer.

Comment: thanks for update answer. you gave all endpoint name same like name="MyserviceHTTP" is it possible??